# How can I put a Header Component above the TopTabNavigator?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to do this where the Header component stands above the TopTabNavigator:[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DCEv.png)

If I hadn't two types of the navigator (Stack and Tab) I could do this: (use `<NavigaionContainer>` and put the Header inside, but it's not my case)

```
//Just an Example
const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

function MyTabs() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Header /> <-- Put the header here
        <Tab.Navigator>
          <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomePage} />
          <Tab.Screen name="Friends" component={FriendsPage} />
          <Tab.Screen name="Store" component={StorePage} />
          <Tab.Screen name="Notifications" component={NotificationsPage} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
```

Here is my code:

```
import Header from './src/components/Header';

const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

function MyTabs() {
    return (
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomePage} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Friends" component={FriendsPage} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Store" component={StorePage} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Notifications" component={NotificationsPage} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}


const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator   initialRouteName="home" screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false
      }} >
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={Register} />
        <Stack.Screen name="MainContent" component={MyTabs} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `header` inside the `options` prop of the `MainContent` screen in your stack navigator to render a custom header for that screen.

Assuming you only want to show a custom header for the top tabs and no header at all for the other screens in the navigator you can do something like this:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName="home"
        screenOptions={({route}) => ({
          headerShown: route.name === 'MainContent',
        })}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={Register} />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="MainContent"
          component={MyTabs}
          options={{header: () => <Header />}}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```